# Doubts about carbon fork condition

Tags: fork, carbon

I've recently bought a second-hand Fuji Jari 1.7 (http://archive.fujibikes.com/2018/Fuji/jari-172). It's in good condition and works without problems, the only thing I'm slightly worried about is the carbon fork.

The fork has weird looks to it. On some areas of the fork it looks like there's some sort of weaving showing, in some places there are lines that look like something left over from molding during production. Some parts, when looked at at a certain angle, are kind of cloudy or milky.

I've never had any carbon on any of my bikes before, so I'm not sure what to think of it. Hopefully this is normal look of raw carbon covered with transparent finish?

Please take a look at the pictures and comment. Otherwise than the strange looks, the fork seems perfectly OK -- the surface is uniform, there's no visible damage apart from some minor scratches on the finish, there are no weird sounds when I tap the fork all over, etc.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some of what you point out could be aftermarket, clear frame protectors - essentially thick tape. You should be able to feel the edges of those (and be able to peel them off easily). Other pictures make me doubt this though...

Comment: As @StefanS says, it looks like its been taped (and looks like they did a really nice job of it too).

Comment: Do you guys mean something like this: https://www.invisiframe.co.uk/X-FUSION/MCQUEEN-29-275-2018?

Comment: That's what I meant, yes. I did not know that they are available pre-cut for individual forks.

Comment: @Radek Yes, that's right

Answer (score 1):

I think what you have is a lower end carbon fork where cost has been saved on the finish.

Carbon fiber composite is made from carbon fiber cloth in an epoxy matrix. The cloth weave often shows through the finish of CFC products. The finish in this fork seems to be somewhat variable. I think you are right that the lines on the inside are mold junction lines. Notice that are all on the inside surface to try to hide them.

What I would be more concerned about are the two vertical crack lines visible in the first photo, running parallel to the mould line above the cable exit. They may just be in the finish but I would have a bike repair shop check them out.

Comment: I think the 'cracks' are where the tape has been creased prior to application.  If you follow them down to the brake hose port, it then takes an angled turn and runs to a corner where the tape can be seen lifting slightly.

Comment: @AndyP after another look I think you are correct - I’m glad to say

Comment: So, the protective tape theory makes sense and when I look at the fork from up close, it really seems like this is it. Except that I can't find any place where the tape layer starts. No place where I could fit any tool in to lift it up a bit and peel it off. The corner where Andy says the tape is lifting slightly -- nothing's lifting there, it's just a light reflection. The surface is perfectly smooth, so either someone did a perfect job with that tape (which I find unlikely), or it's something else. Maybe the paint job has been botched in the factory?

Comment: @Radek if that is the case, then i'd suggest that it has been taped in the past, and the process of removing the tape has somehow damaged the clear coat.  I certainly cant think of anything in the manufacturing process that would produce results like shown in the photos

Comment: It certainly does look like tape or, as you suggest, the effects of peeling one off. Anyway, I'll have it checked in a bike shop just in case. Thanks for all the suggestions!